# Why does Kafka require `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` to be less than of equal to 5 with Idempotency enabled? (`enable.idempotence`)

Tags: apache-kafka

According to the [Kafka documentation for producers](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html):

> enabling idempotence requires `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` to be less than or equal to 5 (with message ordering preserved for any allowable value), retries to be greater than 0, and acks must be ‘all’.

My question is, why the value 5 for `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection`? This seems somewhat arbitrary. I would have expected the value to be 1, if anything, otherwise message re-ordering may occur.

Can someone explain the situation? It is clear to me that I have a misunderstanding here, because idempotency guarantees message ordering, and yet I imagine that if the number of inflight requests is greater than 1, reordering may occur. This is clearly not the case, but why?